# Convert the limit using the compression theorem.

Tags: calculus, compression

How to convert this limit using the squeeze theorem
?

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\sqrt[n]{3^n+(2|\sin(n^n)|)^n}$$

Note that

$$0 \le |\sin(n^n)| \le 1 $$

So, we can write

$$\color{red}{\sqrt[n]{3^n} \le \sqrt[n]{3^n+(2|\sin(n^n)|)^n} \le \sqrt[n]{3^n+2^n}} \le \color{blue}{\sqrt[n]{2\cdot 3^n}}$$

I can roughly imagine how we got $\color{red}{\mathit{the\ three\ parts}}$ of this expression, but I don’t understand how to get the $\color{blue}{\mathit{fourth~part}}$ of this expression and what to do next. Can you please show me what steps i should take next.

Comment: because $2^n\leq 3^n$. to continue, you need to show that $\sqrt[n]{2}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: By the way it is more fun to call it **sandwich theorem** instead of compression theorem...

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{3^n+2^n} \le \sqrt[n]{3^n+3^n}$ That's how I understood it. The following is what I want to say, if my leftmost side is equal to three, then the whole expression will automatically be equal to three. And yes, the compression theorem is the sandwich theorem. In general, this limit will be equal to three. $$\lim_{n\to ∞}\sqrt[n]{3^n+(2|\sin(n^n)|)^n} = 3$$